# c++ problem with build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, build

I have this method declaration in Util.h file

```
 30:string to_string(const bit_vector& v);
```

Util.cc file has the definition

```
 string to_string(const bit_vector& v){
 string str = "";
  for (bit_vector::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i < v.end(); ++i){
    if(*i == 1) str += "1";
    else str += "0";
  }
  return str;
}
```

when I try to build the project it says that in line 30

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
```

Im using visual studio 2008, Can some one help me to get out of these two errors! Dont know whether there is a problem with bit_vector !!! any ideas???

Comment: On a related note, you could use a std::bitset<> instead since it has it's own to_string() method.  Unfortunately, it's a bit of a pain to call.  See the following for details: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitset.html

Comment: For that line 30 to work, you must have previously use a *using* directive. Don't use such directives in header files (http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401782)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `bit_vector` is not defined. There are [claims](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bit_vector.html) that it should be included in `<vector>`, but that doesn't seem to be the case on Visual Studio 2008. Try

```
typedef vector<bool> bit_vector;
```

before the first usage of `bit_vector`.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2008 doesn't define bit_vector by default.

In the  header file it has the following:

```
#if _HAS_TRADITIONAL_STL
 typedef _Bvector bit_vector;
 #define __vector__ vector
#endif /* _HAS_TRADITIONAL_STL */
```

But _HAS_TRADITIONAL_STL doesn't seemed to be defined by default.

Its definition of _Bvector is:

```
typedef vector<bool, allocator<bool> > _Bvector;
```

So you can either #define _HAS_TRADITIONAL_STL before including <vector> or just use vector<bool, allocator<bool>> directly.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it seems like when `uitl.h` is being processed by the compiler it has no idea what a `bit_vector` is.

You'll need to make sure that whatever header declares `bit_vector` is included before that point. You can either include the header for `bit_vector` in `util.h` or you can add an appropriate forward declaration:

```
class bit_vector;
```

Comment: There is no need to include the header in `Util.h`, a forward declaration is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also look at lines before it. The compiler clearly isn't considering bit_vector to be a type in this declaration, so yes the problem could be in the bit_vector declaration.

Answer (score 0):

May be compiler does not know what is string. Write

```
using std::string;
```

Answer (score 0):

bit_vector isn't part of the C++ standard library. It's part of some older non-standard STL implementations though...

SGI's STL [documentation of bit_vector](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bit_vector.html) says:

> Warning: The name bit_vector will be
>   removed in a future release of the
>   STL...not defined in the C++ standard,
>   and is retained only for backward
>   compatibility.

And the only thing on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/19191732-2734-48ab-8e00-c06da999b7e2) is a forum post by on of the VC++ developers:

> bit_vector is not an official part of the C++ Standard and hence is not part of the Visual C++ release.

I certainly wouldn't use `#define _HAS_TRADITIONAL_STL` - it's undocumented and may well disappear in future versions of the Microsoft compiler.